# Queuing distribution for scenario

Tags: queueing-theory, simulation

May I know what is the best queuing distribution to describe the following scenario?
Is it **M/M/2**, **M/G/2**, or other distributions?

> Ships arrive at a harbour with inter-arrival times that are IID
>   exponential random variables with a mean of 1.25 days. The harbour has
>   a dock with two berths, each equipped with a crane for unloading the
>   ships. Ships arriving when both berths are free will select a berth at
>   random. Ships arriving when both berths are occupied join a FIFO
>   queue. The time for one crane to unload a ship is distributed
>   uniformly between 0.5 and 1.5 days.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the usual interpretation of 'Kendall's notation', `M = Markov` or `Memoryless` stands for exponential, and `G = General` stands for non-exponential. Here arrivals are exponential and service times are uniform. So `M/G/2.`

See [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kendall's_notation) for more.